# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] while using imported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module.exports

I am checking if a user is logged in a route called forum. I am importing it like this.
The file is routes/forum.js

```js
const isloggedinimport = require('../index')
```

I have the function on index.js

```js
const isloggedin = (req,res,next) => {
  if(req.user) {
    next()
  }
  else {
    res.render('loginerror',)
  }
}
```

I am exporting with

```
module.exports = isloggedin
```

When I try to run this

```
router.get('/', isloggedinimport.isloggedin, (req, res) => { 
    res.render('monitors/monitorhome')
});


module.exports = router
```

I get the error that Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

The error is on this line

```js
router.get('/', isloggedinimport.isloggedin, (req, res) => {
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you exporting from `index`?

Comment: Just edited the question; module.exports = isloggedin

Comment: You aren't showing where you `require()` in the module with isloggedin in it.  To accurately know what's going on here, we have to see both where you're exporting and where you're requiring.

Comment: You're not exporting an object - loggedIn is the main export, so just use that.

Comment: So I should just do 
const isloggedin = require('../index')

and 
router.get('/', isloggedin,(req, res) => {

while I do
module.exports = isloggedin
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exporting the function, try using the following code:

```
module.exports.isloggedin = isloggedin
```

This will set the property `isloggedin` to the function so that when you call `isloggedinimport.isloggedin`, it will access the function properly. Alternatively, you could use the following code to export your function:

```
module.exports = isloggedin
```

and then use this code to import the function:

```
const isloggedin = require('../index')

...

router.get('/', isloggedin, (req, res) => { 
    res.render('monitors/monitorhome')
});
```

Comment: Where does the isloggedinimport come from though? Would that be isloggedin.isloggedin?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change `isloggedinimport` in the second solution to `isloggedin`. It should be correct now.

Comment: When I run that, I still get the error Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Comment: Did you use the first solution I gave or the second solution?

Comment: Second solution

Comment: Just to verify, you used `module.exports = isloggedin` and not `module.exports.isloggedin = isloggedin`, correct?

Comment: Oh oops I wasn't using your new imports thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and fixed it by adding brackets around the function you want to export:

```
module.exports = {isloggedin};
```